# I move folder to * file type how to get file form it

Tags: xubuntu, files, filesystem, file-format, mv

I try

```
mv Some.txt A*
```

but there is not any folder name of A so it converts into 'A*'file
[ls screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J0IR.png)

Comment: Please check the screenshot then you maybe know the problem

Comment: So it's just renamed file that's it !! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the file back. Example:

```
doug@s19:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls -l
total 88
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doug doug    15 Apr 23 11:08 Some.txt
doug@s19:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ mv Some.txt A*
doug@s19:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls
'A*'
doug@s19:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls -l
total 88
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doug doug    15 Apr 23 11:08 'A*'
doug@s19:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ mv 'A*' Some.txt
doug@s19:~/tmp/tmp/tmp$ ls -l
total 88
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doug doug    15 Apr 23 11:08 Some.txt
```